# How to create a Dynamic Intent in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to know how can I create a 'dynamic intent' in android.

In sum, what I want to accomplish is to show a list of items of data that are being fecthed from a webservice and when an item is clicked to launch a new activity with some parameters set. Note that all the items would be an instance of the same class, that I suppose would extend *Activiy*.

I have managed to list the items, but can't seem to find a way to do the 'dynamic intent' part.

I know the following code doesn't work, but it ilustrates what I am trying to accomplish.

Hope I have made myself understood.

```
if (((TextView) view).getText().equals("Page"))
{    
      MyClass item = new MyClass("foo", "bar");
      myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send any custom or 'dynamic' content through the extras on the intent. These are available to the activity that is launched by the intent.

so you would do something like:

```
myIntent.putExtra("myCutsomDataTag","myCustomData");
```

on the intent that you launch.

In your receiving activity you would do something like:

```
Intent launchIntent = getIntent();
String myCustomData = launchIntent.getStringExtra("myCutsomDataTag");
```

Comment: thanks. that does work, but I need to pass a larger data structure, something like an arraylist with 100 elements. Do you know how I could achieve that?

Comment: That gets a bit more complicated. There are ways to achieve it but it depends on your application layout. If the activities are part of the same application, you could provide a custom application intstance and store the data on there. It would be accessible from both activities. This means that you need to have a custom Application subclass, which whilst it isnt difficult to achieve, makes your model more complicated. Other than this you could use persistent storage (filesystem/db/etc).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply again. I understood the idea. However, I am just starting out with android development and don't think I am capable of figuring it out by myself yet. Wouldn't you mind to provide a simple example with the 'application subclass' architecture? It would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Its not that difficult really. You just need to subclass Application the same way that you do Activity. Provide any storage and methods to access it. You then put an entry in your manifest like android:name="MyApplicationSubclass" in the <application...> node of your manifest. Android will now create an instance of your application subclass instead of the default one. You can access it from your activities by calling getApplication() and casting it to the type of your subclass. This isnt going to be ideal for all solutions as it quite tightly couples your activities together.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write a singleton class where you store the custom data. Once the activity is started you read the data from that singleton...

JPM